# C# returning types re covariance

Tags: c#, overloading, covariance, contravariance

I know this has been covered before but i have not found any good solutions.  In the example I am using two return type classes (ClassA and ClassB) with a returns args class. I have a base class which my ClassXml and ClassText extend from and wish to prevent the specific interface casting in the Print. Is this possible?

The ClassXml and ClassText Execute methods are invoked, which in turn invokes the base class functionality which calls the appropriate print.

```
   using System;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            public class ClassA
            {
                public string Xml
                {
                    get { return "xml"; }
                }
            }

            public class ClassB
            {
                public char Text
                {
                    get { return 't'; }
                }
            }

            public interface IReturnArgs<out T>
            {
                string Name { get; set; }
                T Source { get; }
            }

            public class ReturnArgs<T> : IReturnArgs<T>
                where T : class
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }

                private T _source;

                public T Source
                {
                    get { return _source ?? (_source = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), new object[] {})); }
                }
            }

            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var classA = new ReturnArgs<ClassA>();
                var classB = new ReturnArgs<ClassB>();

                var xml = new ClassXml();
                xml.Execute(classA);

                var text = new ClassText();
                text.Execute(classB);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public abstract class ClassBase
            {
                public void Execute(IReturnArgs<object> args)
                {
                    // Do something common to both classes e.g. run tasks etc (not shown)
                    // calls print when completed, each call specific to child class.

                    Print(args);
                }

                /// <summary>
                /// Abstract print method. Print invokes the child implementation.
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="args"></param>
                public virtual void Print(IReturnArgs<object> args){}
            }

            public class ClassXml : ClassBase
            {
                public void Execute(IReturnArgs<ClassA> args)
                {
                    //invoked externally (Main) calling base common functionality. 

                    base.Execute(args);

                    Print(args);
                }

                //print invoked by child class call - Note if invoked in this class then IReturnArgs<ClassA> could be used 
                //and a cast would not be necessary - however, this would separate common calls accross child classes.
                public void Print(IReturnArgs<ClassA> args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ClassA Source {0}", ((IReturnArgs<ClassA>)args).Source.Xml);//ugly cast
                }
            }

            public class ClassText : ClassBase
            {
                public void Execute(IReturnArgs<ClassB> args)
                {
                    //invoked externally (Main) calling base common functionality. 

                    base.Execute(args);
                }

                //print invoked by base class call which requires the cast IReturnArgs<ClassB> from IReturnArgs<object>
                public override void Print(IReturnArgs<object> args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ClassB Source {0}", ((IReturnArgs<ClassB>)args).Source.Text);//ugly cast
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use a common interface/base class?

Comment: In the example there is a base class called ClassBase.  What i am trying to understand or solve is how to pass ReturnArgs between child/parent classes having it return different return types of Source property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the same thing twice it seems.

`ClassA` and `ClassB` are too strongly related to `ClassXML` and `ClassText`.

To solve this you could put functionality from `ClassXML` in `ClassA` and `ClassText` in `ClassB`.

Alternatively, you could implement something like `ToString()` or another interface (`ITextContent` with method `GetContent())` to return the XML and Text respectively. This way you would only have need of just one `ClassContent` class which just calls the `ITextContent.GetContent()`.

Full fledged example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public Interface ITextContent
        {
           string GetContent();
        }

        public class ClassA : ITextContent
        {
            public string Xml
            {
                get { return "xml"; }
            }

            public string GetContent()
            {
                return this.Xml;
            }
        }

        public class ClassB : ITextContent
        {
            public char Text
            {
                get { return 't'; }
            }

            public string GetContent()
            {
                return this.Text;
            }
        }

        public interface IReturnArgs<out T>
        {
            string Name { get; set; }
            T Source { get; }
        }

        public class ReturnArgs<T> : IReturnArgs<T>
            where T : class
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            private T _source;

            public T Source
            {
                get { return _source ?? (_source = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), new object[] {})); }
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var classA = new ReturnArgs<ClassA>();
            var classB = new ReturnArgs<ClassB>();

            var xml = new ClassContent();
            xml.Execute(classA);

            var text = new ClassContent();
            text.Execute(classB);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class ClassContent
        {
            public void Execute(IReturnArgs<object> args)
            {
                Print(args);
            }

            public void Print(IReturnArgs<object> args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((IReturnArgs<ITextContent>)args).GetContent());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. ClassA and ClassB are there to illustrate the different types of T. I am trying to invoke the execute in the child classes (ClassXml, ClassText) without using IReturnArgs<object> in the base class or without casting at the child level.

Comment: My answer is still the same. By introducing a common interface for ClassA and ClassB which gets you the content you want, you can remove the casting at the child level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have now accepted this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be facing the problem of casting in your child classes, because the base class shouldn't be defining methods whose parameter types depend on child classes. A base class should be a common interface to both, meaning this should always work no matter what I assign to `b` and `args`:

```
ClassBase b;
IReturnArgs<object> args;

...

b.Print(args);
```

But with your classes it will fail if I use `ClassText` and `IReturnArgs<ClassA>` for example.

Why not use a generic base?

```
public abstract class ClassBase<T> {
    public void Execute(IReturnArgs<T> args) { ... }
    public virtual void Print(IReturnArgs<T> args) { ... }
}

public class ClassXml : ClassBase<ClassA> {
   public override void Print(IReturnArgs<ClassA> args) {
       Console.WriteLine("ClassA Source {0}", args.Source.Text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Yes this would work but unfortunately requires my base class to be generic.

Comment: @user3021646 Is there a reason it can't / shouldn't be generic?